# Server application state in Meteor, how to prevent resetting on code change

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor application that uses a node package that takes some time when loading it's resources. Specific package is 'typo-js'. This needs to load a large text file.

The problem I am having is that when I change something on the server, this loading needs to happen each time. This creates an issue in terms of development time as I need to wait a minute before I can run tests.

The way I do it now is that I have a file that handles all my global namespace:

```
G = {};
Meteor.startup(function () {
    G.baseDir = process.cwd().replace(/\/\.meteor.*$/, '');
    G.bot = undefined;
    G.dictionary = undefined;
});
```

I need these globals throughout my app. However, I would like to be able to set their values once, and then not run this file more than once.

This is the way I set these global variables in another file:

```
G.bot = new RiveScript({utf8: true});
G.dictionary = new Typo();
```

What I would like is to be able to change server-side code but retain the values set above to the global namespace. The two lines of code that set the global variables take quite some time to load.

Comment: i would turn the long-booting parts into their own microservice, so that they never have to reboot. a production app itself should not take longer than 100ms to boot from scratch...

Comment: @dandavis Ok, could you explain what a microservice is?

Comment: maybe, you should work with a mock during development, just as an idea..

Comment: @webdeb yes, I could probably use mock files so loading does not take long. I was just wondering if there are ways where I could get my cake and eat it too.

Comment: ask your mom for a cake and eat it ;)